# Jekyll Markdown and Staticrypt

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I'm using Staticrypt to password protect a website page. Here is the generator:

https://robinmoisson.github.io/staticrypt/

But it asks for html content. I want to use Jekyll Markdown instead and let it autogenerate the page. How do I do it?

Comment: If that service needs HTML content, you can't use Markdown. First convert your Markdown content to HTML.

Comment: Jekyll is a static site generator. Use Jekyll to build your HTML locally, then provide the generated HTML to the service.